# Install Pyhash in Amazon EC2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, hash

I am trying to isntall Pyhash which is a third party package providing various hash functions in python. I installed this package in ec2 usign easy_install.

However whenever i am trying to import pyhash i get the following error

```
ImportError: libboost_python-py26.so.1.42.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have boost, boost-python already installed in the ami linux.

Any suggestions?

Also is there any other python package providing Murmurhash1 ?

Answer (score 0):

The libboost_python-py26.so.1.42.0 cannot be found. You should add the path of it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH